# Moving Ubuntu and Windows from separate drives to single drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, ssd, clone

I currently have three hard drives in my machine that I dual-boot:
- 1TB for data
- 80GB win 7
- 240GB Ubuntu (only using less than half)

I just got a new 256GB SSD, and I'd like to end up with both the win 7 and the ubuntu installations dualbooted on this drive.

I've got no experience with cloning drives, but I understand the concepts. Here's my plan, and I'm interested in feedback before I sink a ton of time into it.

- Resize the /home partition on the ubuntu drive so that the entire linux installation is 176GB.
- Boot into something from a DVD
- Clone the windows drive into the SSD
- Copy (dd?) the 176GB from the linux partitions to the rest of the drive

Will this work?
Will I need to do some repair to get the bootloaders working? Ideally, I'd like to boot into GRUB2 and have the choice of Win7 or Ubuntu.
What software would you recommend booting to? Would the Ubuntu live CD be good for this?
Can you direct me at any references on how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Oops. seperate *drives, not drivers.

Comment: You can try CloneZilla(http://clonezilla.org/)